# Packing/Appending element in specific positions to create a tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples, packing

I am fairly new to python, so bear with me.

Say I have two lists:

```
    >>> doors = [1,2,3]
    >>> prizes = ['green','blue','red']
```

And then I want to shuffle the list prizes (I already imported random):

```
    >>> random.shuffle(prizes)
    >>> print('shuffled_prizes=',prizes)
    prizes= ['blue', 'green', 'red']
```

Is there a way I can insert these into the doors list/make them tuples? Such that doors' positioning stays intact, but the prizes are just put in respectively:

```
    wanted_output = [(1, 'blue'),(2,'green'),(3,'red')]
```

I have heard of packing with

```
*args
```

but I am still not having a clear understanding of how that works either. If someone could help me keep the prizes shuffled, but put them shuffled together with doors in the same position, that would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `zip` function. There is no need to use tuple packing-unpacking:

```
list(zip(doors, prizes))
```